# Have code which will run before every test in one location

Tags: protractor

I have (or will have) a large number of tests, so far in each of these tests I am calling a beforeEach function (to start the browser and set the size of the window) - and this function is the same for everything.  This seems to be a little wasteful.  In java, I used to create a base class and then have all my tests extend from this - so if I had to make any changes it was in that one place.  Can protractor do the same?

I've had a look around and so far I am thinking it isn't going to be possible, but before I give up I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Protractor then you don't need to care about starting browser.

You can maximize the window once at the protractor configuration file using `onPrepare()` method.

Comment: Sorry - serves me right for posting a question late at night.  In my beforeEach I set window size, is is this which is repeated:

    beforeEach(function() {

`        browser.get(browser.baseUrl)
            .then(() => browser.sleep(0));
        //browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1920,1080);
        browser.driver.manage().window().setPosition(0,0);

     });`

Comment: You don't need maximaze each time. Make it once on `onPrepare`. Also why you do `browser.sleep(0)`? There is no sense to do it.

Comment: that was part of an experiment which I've left by mistake

Comment: do you mean onPrepare in the config file?